# Power automate - Unable to get JSON content from Sharepoint folder

Tags: json, sharepoint, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow that gets a JSON file from a SharePoint folder (when dropped into it) and I want to be able to read its contents and extract a key/value.
The issue I am having is that it crashes in the second step, Get File Content, with the error

> Encountered internal server error. The tracking Id is
> '3bc1890c-1932-4a2e-af14-6e5cca1534be'.

I realized that it has to do with the JSON file's syntax. When I ran the flow with the below JSON file

```
{
    "products": {
      "GF": [
        {
          "product_name": "GF",
          "remediation": {
            "type": "package",
            "packages": [
              {
                "service": "av",
                "service_name": "AV",
                "description": "Detects Prestige ransomware payloads",
                "kill_chain": {
                  "step": "Delivery"
                },
                "link": "https://www.GF.com/updates/antivirus?version=90.06850",
                "minimum_version": "90.06850"
              }
            ]
          },
          "detection": {
            "virus": [
              "W32/Filecoder.OMM!tr.ransom"
            ],
            "virusid": [
              10108353
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "title": "Prestige Ransomware",
    "sub_title": "Impacting organizations in Ukraine and Poland",
    "link": "https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2022/10/14/new-prestige-ransomware-impacts-organizations-in-ukraine-and-poland/",
    "cve_list": [
      "TBA"
    ],
    "description": "Researchers at Microsoft Threat Intelligence Center (MSTIC) have identified evidence of a novel ransomware campaign targeting organizations in the transportation and logistics industries in Ukraine and Poland. According to the report, the new ransomware labels itself with a ransom note of “Prestige ranusomeware”.",
    "tag": "Prestige Ransomware",
    "event_handler_desc": "",
    "m": 851548,
    "additional_resources": [
      {
        "Source": "Microsoft Security Blog",
        "Link": "https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2022/10/14/new-prestige-ransomware-impacts-organizations-in-ukraine-and-poland/"
      }
    ],
    "ob_url": "https://www.GF.com/ob-alert/prestige-ransomware"
  }
```

the PA workflow executes successfully. However, when I try with the same PA workflow with the JSON file below (the required one)

```
[
  {
    "products": {
      "GF": [
        {
          "product_name": "GF",
          "remediation": {
            "type": "package",
            "packages": [
              {
                "service": "av",
                "service_name": "AV",
                "description": "Detects Prestige ransomware payloads",
                "kill_chain": {
                  "step": "Delivery"
                },
                "link": "https://www.GF.com/updates/antivirus?version=90.06850",
                "minimum_version": "90.06850"
              }
            ]
          },
          "detection": {
            "virus": [
              "W32/Filecoder.OMM!tr.ransom"
            ],
            "virusid": [
              10108353
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "title": "Prestige Ransomware",
    "sub_title": "Impacting organizations in Ukraine and Poland",
    "link": "https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2022/10/14/new-prestige-ransomware-impacts-organizations-in-ukraine-and-poland/",
    "cve_list": [
      "TBA"
    ],
    "description": "Researchers at Microsoft Threat Intelligence Center (MSTIC) have identified evidence of a novel ransomware campaign targeting organizations in the transportation and logistics industries in Ukraine and Poland. According to the report, the new ransomware labels itself with a ransom note of “Prestige ranusomeware”.",
    "tag": "Prestige Ransomware",
    "event_handler_desc": "",
    "m": 851548,
    "additional_resources": [
      {
        "Source": "Microsoft Security Blog",
        "Link": "https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2022/10/14/new-prestige-ransomware-impacts-organizations-in-ukraine-and-poland/"
      }
    ],
    "ob_url": "https://www.GF.com/ob-alert/prestige-ransomware"
  }
]
```

the workflow crashes with the error I posted in the beginning of my post. It seems that the initial and ending [ ] make the workflow step of Get File Content to crash.

The problem is that this is the actual JSON syntax I need to work with.
Any idea or suggestion would ne very valuable, because I have been working on it for the last couple of days and I am stuck BIG TIME!

The PA workflow is the below
[image]

Thank you in advance,
Nikos

Comment: Just an additional information. If I rename the JSON file to {filename}.txt it goes through fine. Is there a way to rename the JSON file before I execute the "Get file content" step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content of the file can't be inferred (because the file doesn't have an extension) that action returns a base64 string.

[image: Data]

When you rename the file with an extension of `.txt` it infers the content as text and therefore works.

Rather than rename the file, which if you want to make it perfect will require elements of pain depending on the approach you take, you can simply decode the base64 string in the `$content` field by using an expression like this ...

```
decodeBase64(body('Get_file_content')?['$content'])
```

... within the **Content** field of the **Parse JSON** action but within the `Expression` section, not the `Dynamic content` section.

[image: Expression]

That should give you what you want.

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi @Skin, thank you for your reply. I tried your solution and I get the following error:

"The 'content' property of actions of type 'ParseJson' must be valid JSON. The provided value cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: d. Path '', line 0, position 0.'." 

In the "Get file content" step the option "Infer content type" is NO, otherwise it crashes. I followed your suggestion to enter "decodeBase64(body('Get_file_content')?['$content'])" in the "Content" field of the "Parse JSON" step. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the JSON response from the Get File Contents step?  Impossible to help without it.

Comment: Hi @Skin, I posted my reply above in order to paste some screen shots for your reference. Thank you

Comment: My answer still stands, you need to enter the expression into the expression window, not the dynamic properties.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Skin, Yes it worked now!!! Thank you for pointing out my mistake. After I entered your answer (decodeBase64(body('Get_file_content')?['$content'])) using the Expression window of the Parse JSON step, I got the JSON output that I wanted. I greatly appreciate your help and...patience. Take care :)